# Square brackets in zsh completion function argument description, possible?

Tags: zsh, zsh-completion

Basically, I'm wondering if its possible to do this:

```
#compdef foo
_arguments \
    '--arg=[Description of --arg [With square brackets in the string!]]' \
```

without getting an `invalid option error` due to the nested square brackets?

I've tried all manner of escape characters.  Single vs. double quotes makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try to escaping them like this:

```
'--arg=\\[Description of --arg \\[With square brackets in the string!\\]\\]'
```